# Destructure Object and send only Child Variables

Tags: typescript

I'm dealing with http in Angular to make requests to an API, and I'm trying to figure out a better way to send the objects I need.

Problem: 
API is already made and receives data as: `{name: 'Rafael', id: 8, etc...}`. Everything I need to send is straight in the root of the JSON.

The solution I've been using so far is quite time consuming, since I need to specify every single variable and assign it's value, even though they already have the same name.

I'm using just name and id here to exemplificate but there's quite a few.

```js
this.http.put<any>(`url`, {name: user.name, id: user.id})
```

However, since the API is designed to receive requests with a gigantic body and I can't change anything in it, this is really time consuming.

I then tried to send the user variable as follows:

```js
this.http.put<any>(`url`, {user})
```

But then the body of the request looks like `{user: {name, id...}}`

I also tried a bit of object destructuring (as below), which worked better, but still involves quite a bit of work.

```js
({ name, id} = user);
```

Is there any way I can just destructure my `user` and have an object with just it's variables?

Sorry if I'm not clear enough, I'm still quite new to this Typescript world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the spread operator and specify as `{...user}` rather than `{user}`.  This should take all the keys inside `user` and make a duplicate array with the same values in a new object that you then pass to the `http.put` as you did above.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that actually helped. However, since it's an array, I had to workaround and do {...user[0]}. 

Is this the right way?

Comment: Hard to say because I don't know what other data is encompassed in the array but if the first index always will hold the info you need then yes.  As I said above it just will take all the key: value pairs in the user array at index 0 and create an object with those exact values.

Comment: So even if I use the spread for a single object it still gives me an array? I guess I'll have to experiment a bit with this. Sounds quite interesting